# What is the purpose of declaring a function like !function(){ code }();

Tags: javascript

What is the purpose of declaring a function like:

```
!function(){ code }();
```

Why the `!`?

Comment: Can you post a more detailed example?

Comment: This is an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression). For info on why you might use one see this article: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In JavaScript, you can declare and execute a function in one shot**, but doing it like this:

```
function() { /* ... */ }();
```

is a syntax error.

**You can make it work by forcing the parser to recognise the function declaration as part of an *expression* rather than as a *statement***:

```
(function() { /* ... */ }());
```

What you're seeing is an alternative way of doing this, by using the `!` operator. It'll negate the function's result but, here, that result (if there is one) is ignored anyway.

```
!function() { /* ... */ }();
```

In other words, it's a bit of a hack.

---

Further reading:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression
- http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: I don't see why it's "nasty". Removing the outer parentheses makes the code more readable IMHO.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd: It's "nasty" that you have to do this at all.

Comment: It's a real shame that IIFEs are so inelegant, isn't it?

Comment: @AndrewShepherd -- The biggest reason to prefer parens over the `!` is that you can return a value from the IIFE.  When you do so, the parens are there to **help the reader of the code** by following a standardized convention.  Sure, the compiler doesn't care -- but people do.

Answer (score 4):

It tells the interpreter that the function keyword following is part of a function expression rather than a declaration. This allows the function to be executed immediately, creating a namespaced, encapsulated module.

A more common approach is to wrap the function keyword and body in parens. This is sometimes called an 'IIFE' or module pattern.